# How can I remove the string from a character in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have some URLs and I need some of them to be stripped from the question mark (?)

Ex. `https://www.yelp.com/biz/starbucks-san-leandro-4?large_photo=1`

I need it to return `https://www.yelp.com/biz/starbucks-san-leandro-4`

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try so far? What research did you make before asking the question here?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research?

Comment: I don't know. Thats why I ask others.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `.split()` method

> The split() method splits a string into a list.
>
> You can specify the separator, default separator is any whitespace.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> string.split(separator, maxsplit)
> ```

```
data = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/starbucks-san-leandro-4?large_photo=1'
print (data.split('?')[0])
```

output:

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/starbucks-san-leandro-4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rfind` and slice the string up to the returned index:

```
s = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/starbucks-san-leandro-4?large_photo=1'

s[:s.rfind('?')]
# 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/starbucks-san-leandro-4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Go for a regular expression

```
import re

new_string = re.sub(r'\?.+$', '', your_string)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ArqBEC/1).

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the url and the rebuild it with the parts that you want to keep. For example you can use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)